# Throwing an exception when a user session has expired or returning null

Tags: java, session, exception, java-8

This question is more about design and clean code, I'm having a hard time understanding when a checked expection should be thrown or when we should return a null value and check on the client if this value is null or not.

As far I read, checked exceptions should be used in cases where a exceptional situation can happen but we cannot prevent it. Also I have read that we should not use exceptions as control flow.

So in my case, I'm writing a concurrent application where a lot of users will make requests, and I have a method where I check if the user session is expired or not (and it expires after 10 minutes), so, teorically I should throw an exception there because I can not prevent this situation, but on the other side if that situation is going to happen every 10 minutes, exceptions are expensive and maybe if I return a null and I do the check on the client would be better for performance. What would you do in this case?

this is my method:

```
@Override
public Integer getUserIdBySessionKey(String sessionKey) {
    User user = userSessions.get(sessionKey);
    boolean isUserSessionValid = isUserSessionValid(user);
    return isUserSessionValid ? user.getUserId() : null;
}
```

Comment: *I have a method where I check if the user session is expired or not*: then I would return true if the session is expired, and false otherwise. I guess that your method doesn't actually do that. Post the code rather than describing it.

Comment: @JB Nizet, done. My question is, so far I'm returning null is session is not valid, but I could thrown an "ExpiredSessionException", maybe is not a big deal to choose between one option or another but I would like to do it in the most clean way possible

Comment: If there is a chance for the calling code to recover from this case, then I would return an Optional<Integer>. If, on the other hand, the calling code shouldn't deal with this case, and you just want a global exception handler to be called when the session is invalid, then I would throw a runtime exception. In any case, I would not throw a checked exception.

Comment: Ok that's useful thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use checked exceptions when you want to signal to the calling code an important exceptional situation that has to be taken into account, and for which a meaningful action can be taken. For example, when authenticating a user, the password may be wrong or the account expired, so a checked AuthenticationException or AccountExpiredException could be reasonable. The client code would catch these exceptions and handle them appropriately.

On the other hand, situations where there is no reasonable action to take or which are generic enough that they can be handled in a generic way, should be unchecked exceptions. Any coding errors (NullPointerException, IllegalStateException, database errors, network errors etc.) fall into this category.

So the question is, do you expect the calling code to do something about session expired? If you have a generic mechanism to handle this situation (e.g a top level ServletFilter or similar) that catches such exceptions and redirects to the login page, then make it an unchecked exception. If this needs particular attention from the calling code, then make it checked.

In your case I would make it unchecked and handle it in a generic way at the top level.

Comment: Well, from the client side I only need to know which kind of exception is, to return to the client the appropiate http error ( 400 Unathorized in this case). If I do that with a runtime exception, I cannot distinct between exceptions. SO maybe in this case a checked expcetion would fit better, but I can distinct it anyway if instead of sending an expcetion I return an Optional<Integer> and I do the check on the client if(optional.isPresent) return Http.Unathorized, right?

Comment: You can create your SessionExpiredException that extends RuntimeException. This will make it an unchecked exception that you can catch and handle appropriately (by returning 400) at the top level. No need to create a checked exception.

Comment: And by the way, returning null or a status code is not the Java way of handling exceptional situations. It's appropriate in C (or other languages that don't have an exception handling mechanism), but not in Java.